# How to use nested If(AND,true,false) in a formula on SharePoint

Tags: content-type

My formula uses the values from two columns, Stage and Confidence, to calculate Probability of Close.  The nested IF works well for calculating the IF *statements (Stage = 0 thru 7), where the last FALSE = 1*.

```
=IF(Stage="0 - Not Applicable",0,IF(Stage="1 - Identify Opportunity",0.1*Confidence,IF(Stage="2 - Qualify Opportunity",0.25*Confidence,IF(Stage="3 - Develop Response",0.5*Confidence,IF(Stage="4 - Submit Estimate/Proposal",0.65*Confidence,IF(Stage="5 - Work the Opportunity",0.75*Confidence,IF(Stage="6 - Negotiate/SOW",0.9*Confidence, 1)))))))
```

Instead of the last FALSE statement to calculate using 1, I want the last statement to evaluate the values from two separate fields, Stage and Outcome, to provide the result for Probability of Close.

```
If True
Stage = “7 – Close” and Outcome = “Lost”, then Probability of Close = 0, 
Else if True
    Stage = 7 – Close” and Outcome = “Win”, then Probability of Close = 1,
Else if False
    Probability of Close = .5 * Confidence
```

I tried using the *IF(AND(Stage ="7 - Close",Outcome ="Win",1,0.5*Confidence) for Stage 7 (see following formula)* and am getting the following error:
**The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported**.

```
=IF(Stage="0 - Not Applicable",0,IF(Stage="1 - Identify Opportunity",0.1*Confidence,IF(Stage="2 - Qualify Opportunity",0.25*Confidence,IF(Stage="3 - Develop Response",0.5*Confidence,IF(Stage="4 - Submit Estimate/Proposal",0.65*Confidence,IF(Stage="5 - Work the Opportunity",0.75*Confidence,IF(Stage="6 - Negotiate/SOW",0.9*Confidence, IF(AND(Stage ="7 - Close",Outcome="lost",0,IF(AND(Stage ="7 - Close",Outcome ="Win",1,0.5*Confidence)))))))))))
```

Is there a way in SharePoint to evaluate using nested IF(AND,true,false) or is there another formula to use to evaluate the values?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're missing some parenthesis or not calling AND quite right, here is what you currently have with some returns...

```
=IF(Stage="0 - Not Applicable",0,
IF(Stage="1 - Identify Opportunity",0.1*Confidence,
IF(Stage="2 - Qualify Opportunity",0.25*Confidence,
IF(Stage="3 - Develop Response",0.5*Confidence,
IF(Stage="4 - Submit Estimate/Proposal",0.65*Confidence,
IF(Stage="5 - Work the Opportunity",0.75*Confidence,
IF(Stage="6 - Negotiate/SOW",0.9*Confidence, 
IF(AND(Stage ="7 - Close",Outcome="lost",0,
IF(AND(Stage ="7 - Close",Outcome ="Win",1,
0.5*Confidence
)))))))))))
```

Entering each line this way is just a technique, but it makes it much easier to read because I can see:

```
IF(conditional, true,
false/IF(conditional, true, 
...
else
countUpClosingParens
```

AND can accept multiple parameters, but they should all evaluate to true or false, and you should use the result of your AND evaluation as the first condition for each IF. Let's focus on the last nested statements...

You have:

```
IF(AND(Stage ="7 - Close",Outcome="lost",0,
IF(AND(Stage ="7 - Close",Outcome ="Win",1,
0.5*Confidence
))
```

This should be:

```
IF(AND(Stage ="7 - Close",Outcome="lost"),0,
IF(AND(Stage ="7 - Close",Outcome ="Win"),1,
0.5*Confidence
))
```

Note how AND() is contained to become the single first parameter that each IF expects.

Note if you do this to fix the original formula, you'll need to remove two parens from the last line to make things even (one paren on the last line for each IF line above it).

Answer (score 0):

John-o is correct, you have some syntax errors. But since you have more than 7 IF statements, you'll have to link them together with `&`

```
=IF([Stage]="0 - Not Applicable",0,IF([Stage]="1 - Identify Opportunity",0.1*[Confidence],IF([Stage]="2 - Qualify Opportunity",0.25*[Confidence],IF([Stage]="3 - Develop Response",0.5*[Confidence],IF([Stage]="4 - Submit Estimate/Proposal",0.65*[Confidence],IF([Stage]="5 - Work the Opportunity",0.75*[Confidence],IF([Stage]="6 - Negotiate/SOW",0.9*[Confidence], 1)))))))&IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="lost"),0,IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="Win"),1,0.5*Confidence))
```

Note the last part:

```
&IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="lost"),0,IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="Win"),1,0.5*Confidence))
```

**Update:**

Change the last part:

```
&IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="Lost"),0,IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="Win"),1,IF(Stage="7 - Close", 0.5*Confidence, "")))
```

And the reason you don't get %, is that when you add `&` to the formula its handled as a string, not a number. So you could add that yourself, the number * 100 and add a % behind.

Comment: Oh yeah... I have run in to this before a few years ago, but it doesn't seem to matter anymore, at least on an O365 site -- the article I found talking about nesting limits only references 2007: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/if-function-HA001161010.aspx and testing with OP's formula on my site checks out fine (again, on O365)

Comment: Aha, great finally :)

Comment: The formula works, however, the results displayed in the Probability of Close are different than expected:

Comment: Stage: 7 – Close
Confidence: 100%
Outcome:  Win
Probability of Close:
  Expected:  100%
  Actual:  FALSE1
  NOTE:  Probability of Close should display as 100%

Stage: 3 - Develop Response
Confidence: 90%
Outcome:  No Decision
Probability of Close (should display as 100%:
  Expected:  45%
  Actual:  0.450.45
  NOTE:  Probability of Close should 
         display as 0.5*Confidence = 45%

Comment: Stage: 5 - Work the Opportunity
Confidence: 50%
Outcome:  Lost
Probability of Close (should display as 100%:
  Expected:  38%
  Actual:  0.3750.25
  NOTE:  Probability of Close should 
         display as 0.75*Confidence = 38%

Stage: 7 - Close
Confidence: 25%
Outcome:  No Decision
Probability of Close (should display as 100%:
  Expected:  45%
  Actual:  FALSE0.125
  NOTE:  Probability of Close should 
         display as 0.5*Confidence = 45%

Comment: Oops!  As I was copying the scenarios, I inadvertently copied the comment should display as 100% for each...disregard for the last three and instead reference the NOTE.

Comment: @SKD make sure that when you edit the calculated column you select 'The data type returned from this formula is:' number, then at the bottom check 'Show as Percentage'

Comment: I checked and the formatting is set to number and show as percentage.  The formatting worked correctly before I added the IF AND statements.  Is there something else I should check?

Comment: @SKD Hmm making sure that it returns a number and show as percent works on my O365 environment -- is the [Confidence] column in your list holding numbers (instead of just text)?

Comment: @SKD yeah, check IF([Stage]="6 - Negotiate/SOW",0.9*[Confidence], 1) <-- Change the 1 to ""

Comment: The change from Anders resolved the FALSE, thanks!  In response to John's question, Confidence is formatted as a number with percentage.  If I remove the logic for Stage 7, the results show correctly as percent.  All the results using Stage 7 show number instead of percentage, e.g., the scenarios show 1 (instead of 100% for Win) and 0.450.45 (instead of 45% for No Decision).  Is my syntax for adding the IF AND for Stage 7 correct - IF(Stage="6 - Negotiate/SOW",0.9*Confidence,"")))))))&IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="Lost"),0,IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="Win"),1,0.5*Confidence)) ?

Comment: @SDK The reason you get .45 is the last IF. I'll update my answer

Comment: The formula works, thank you!  Working with SharePoint calculations is new to me, could I get your assistance?  The results of the calculation for other than Stage 7 are not formatting as percentage with no decimals, e.g., IF(Stage="4 - Submit Estimate/Proposal",0.65*Confidence, is displaying as 0.650% instead of 65%.  It worked well until I added the &IF for Stage 7...IF(Stage="6 - Negotiate/SOW",0.9*Confidence,"")))))))&IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="Lost"),"0%",IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="Win"),"100%",IF(AND(Stage="7 - Close",Outcome="No Decision"),0.5*Confidence,"0%")))